# Returning even numbers from a stack?

Tags: java, stack

How do I pass a stack of integers, which returns the number of even numbers. The stack must remain unchanged after the method finishes execution. And Return null if the stack is empty.

This is what i got so far, sorry i am a beginner.

```
public static int countEven(Stack<Integer> stk) {

        Stack stack = new stack();
        int count = 0;

        while (int i=0; i<stack.length; i++);        
            int value = s.pop();

            if (stack %2 == 0);                       
                count++;

            stack.push(value);

        while (int i=0; stack != 0; i++);
            s.push(stack.pop());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you code in Python before learning Java? Just curious. Anyway, you need to learn the basic syntax - specifically, how to use curly braces `{` / `}` and especially where to place semicolons.

Comment: This code does not compile. Please take a book and learn the basics of the language. I suggest to learn the iteration constructs and the scope of variables. Try also with an IDE that your code compile before submitting to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You check the stack on modulo 2? You have to check the value in the Stack.
Also you can use the "get"-function. It only gives you the value in the Stack (for the given index) without removing it.

If you return an integer, you cannot return null. Just return -1 instead...

```
public static int countEven(Stack<Integer> stk) {

    int count = 0;
    if (stk.size() == 0) 
        return -1;

    while (int i=0; i<stk.size(); i++) {
        int value = stk.get(i);
        if (value %2 == 0)                       
            count++;
    }    

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the elements from the stack. You can obtain an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and iterate over all elements and process your check.

Your method could look like.

```
static int countEven(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    // get an Iterator for the passed stack
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = stack.iterator();
    int count = 0;
    // as long the iterator would return another element process the loop
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        // check if the integer is even
        if (iterator.next() % 2 == 0) {
            // increase the even counter
            count++;
        }
    }
    // return the count, if there was no element returned by the iterator
    // `count` would not have been incremented and therefor return zero
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify you stack or use another stack to get all the elements using `java.util.Stack`

`Stack` extends `Vector`, so you can use `get(int)`

```
public static int countEven(Stack<Integer> stack) {
    // Return 0 if the stack is empty
    if (stack == null || stack.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    int count = 0;
    int size = stack.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {        
        int value = stack.get(i); // get ith element
        if (value % 2 == 0)                       
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

As you are new to Java, I suggest you go through few basics about Java.
You can refer this tutorial on [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_syntax.htm)